# append a list at the end of each row of 2D array

Tags: arrays, numpy, append

I want to append a list/1d array (b) at the end of each row of a 2d array (a)

input:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
b = np.array([4, 4])
```

desired out:

```
array([[1, 1, 4, 4],
       [2, 2, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

my code:

```
temp = []
for i in range(len(a)):
   c = np.hstack((a[i], b))
   temp.append(c)
d = np.vstack(temp)
```

is there any better and fast solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
b = np.array([4, 4])

c = np.tile(b[np.newaxis,:], (a.shape[0],1))
d = np.concatenate((a,c), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Joel. What I understand you tiled up `b` to match the shape of `a` then concatenated. but did not understand `b[np.newaxis,:]`. Instead `np.tile(b, (a.shape[0],1))` also worked.

Comment: I just added the `np.newaxis` bit to make `b` two-dimensional. You're right, it works without that so you can ignore.

Comment: is this faster than the first loop-based method?