# I want to add a numpy array to the end of every every row in another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to combine two numpy arrays. `np.concatenate/vstack/hstack` only adds it to the end of the array but I want to add it to the end of every row in the array.

If I have the numpy array,

```
([[1,3,1],
[2,5,3],
 [4,8,4]])
```

And at the end of every row I want to add another numpy array `([8,9,5,5,3,1])`.

So in the end the final array looks like this:

```
([[1,3,1,8,9,5,5,3,1],
[2,5,3,8,9,5,5,3,1],
[4,8,4,8,9,5,5,3,1]])
```

Keep in mind these do have different shapes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [append a list at the end of each row of 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530223/append-a-list-at-the-end-of-each-row-of-2d-array)

Comment: Some what, my issue is that the arrays are different shapes and I dont know how to tackle that

Comment: So you have a (3,3) and want to make a (3,9) by adding a (6,)?  How about `hstack` of a `(3,6)`?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you find it useful.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,3,1],[2,5,3], [4,8,4]])
b = np.array([8,9,5,5,3,1])
b = b[None,:].repeat(3,axis=0)

print(np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using numpy's libraries to repeat the row

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,3,1],[2,5,3], [4,8,4]])
b = np.array([8,9,5,5,3,1])
b = np.tile(b,(3,1))
res = np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1)
print(res)
```

```
array([[8, 9, 5, 5, 3, 1],
       [8, 9, 5, 5, 3, 1],
       [8, 9, 5, 5, 3, 1]])
```